# Failing to start containers on Ubuntu server (Time out on pypi.org)

Tags: docker-compose, celery

I fail to start Docker container on Ubuntu host with docker-compose. This error is thrown:

```
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/celery/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/celery/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/celery/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/celery/
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ReadTimeoutError("HTTPSConnectionPool(host='pypi.org', port=443): Read timed out. (read timeout=15)")': /simple/celery/
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement celery==5.0.5 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for celery==5.0.5
ERROR: Service 'celery' failed to build: The command '/bin/sh -c pip install -r requirements.txt' returned a non-zero code: 1`
```

I tried to set the `--default-timeout=100` parameter in Dockerfile:t

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt --default-timeout=100
`` ``
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a simple terminal restart seems to fix the issue.
If that doesn't do anything and you are on Windows there is this workaround as well:

> Step 1:
> Press Win+R to open Run, type in “regedit” and click OK.
> Step 2:
> Move to HKEY_CURRENT_USER/Software/Microsoft/Windows/Current Version/Internet Settings.
> Step 3:
> Find a file with the name 'ProxyServer' and delete it.
> Step 4:
> Open cmd
> Step 5:
> Fire a command 'pip install flask-bcrypt'

[From a GitHub Discussion](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/7424#issuecomment-589675343)